# Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {type, props}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, react-functional-component

I am trying to implement React.createElement().But I am getting following error

> Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {type, props}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

But when I try original function {React.createElement} mine is {Reacto.createElement} it works
but if I log the element returned from Original and mine function they are pretty much same

Here is code

```
import {createRoot} from "react-dom/client";
import  React from "react";


function createTextElement(text){
    return text
}

function createElement( type , props , ...children ){
    return{
        type,
        props : {
            ...props,
            children : children.map(child =>
                typeof child === "object"
                ? child
                : createTextElement(child)
            ),
        },
    }
}

const Reacto = {
    createElement,
}
//Calling mine function
const element = Reacto.createElement(
    'h1',
    { className: 'greeting' },
    "This is another",
    'Hello'
);
//calling Reacts function
const elementReact = React.createElement(
    'h1',
    { className: 'greeting' },
    'Hello',
    "This is another"
);
//logging both elements
console.log(element);
console.log(elementReact);
const root = createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(element)
```

Here is some logs

This is my element

```
Object { type: "h1", props: {…} }
​
props: Object { className: "greeting", children: (2) […] }
​​
children: Array [ "This is another", "Hello" ]
​​​
0: "This is another"
​​​
1: "Hello"
​​​
length: 2
​​​
<prototype>: Array []
​​
className: "greeting"
​​
<prototype>: Object { … }
​
type: "h1"
​
<prototype>: Object { … }
```

This is Reacts element

```
Object { "$$typeof": Symbol("react.element"), type: "h1", key: null, ref: null, props: {…}, _owner: null, _store: {…}, … }
​
"$$typeof": Symbol("react.element")
​
_owner: null
​
_self: null
​
_source: null
​
_store: Object { … }
​
key: null
​
props: Object { className: "greeting", children: (2) […] }
​​
children: Array [ "Hello", "This is another" ]
​​​
0: "Hello"
​​​
1: "This is another"
​​​
length: 2
​​​
<prototype>: Array []
​​
className: "greeting"
​​
<prototype>: Object { … }
​
ref: null
​
type: "h1"
```

I dont know whats happening anything will help if you know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React is specifically looking for the `$$typeof` property to identify it as being a react element:

```
"$$typeof": Symbol("react.element")
```

Not only does it have to have that property, it has to have one of a few predefined symbols on that property. The symbols aren't exported by react, but you can get them via `Symbol.for("react.element")` or similar. "react.element" is the most common, but you can see others in [this file](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/main/packages/shared/ReactSymbols.js). You may also need to add other properties to finish fooling react, such as `ref: null`.

There's a few spots in the react codebase where they check for `$$typeof`, but here's one: https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/main/packages/react-reconciler/src/ReactChildFiber.js#L534 . The exception you're seeing is thrown a few lines later, by this code:

```
throwOnInvalidObjectType(returnFiber, newChild);
```

Comment: You can reproduce them if you grab it from the global symbol registery: `$$typeof: Symbol.for('react.element')` ([where it seems to be defined](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/1d5667a1273386f84e416059af7b6aba069e068e/packages/shared/ReactSymbols.js#L15)). Also looks like `ref: null` is required otherwise a ref issue is thrown.

Comment: Thanks @NickParsons, i've updated my answer. I don't use symbols often enough, so i forgot about Symbol.for!

Comment: Thanks! exactly that was the reason as Now when I update DOM using javascript it worked